# How to ignore attribute when mapping to json from a text file to a Java object using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a text file 'input.txt' which contains this text

```
{
  "product" : {
    "name" : "Pro-1",
    "category" : "A"
  }
}
```

and a class

```
public class  Product {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("category")
    public String category
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am using Jackson

```
Product p = mapper.readValue(new File("input.txt"), Product.class);
```

My class has no attribute named "product" and as a result exception occurs when mapping the json text to the product object. So, what will be a proper way ignore this "product" attribute when mapping to Product object from the text file?

Comment: Did you try using the [Annotation Type XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)?

Comment: In that case rather JsonRootName, but just have a look at my link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this.

```
public class OuterClass{
    @JsonProperty("product")
    public Product product;
}

OuterClass outerObject = mapper.readValue(new File("input.txt"), OuterClass.class);
```

then you can use it `outerObject.product`